# Visual Studio 2022 - UWP unwanted panel

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to find my way in Visual Studio 2022, C# and UWP. Each time I make an application and also when I run examples prepared by Microsoft, I get a panel with 9 buttons like shown at the middle of the snapshot below. How do I exclude that panel?
[image: unwanted panel]

Comment: This is only a debugging tool, run your program outside of your IDE and it is gone.

Answer (score 0):

If you actualy want to remove the debug toolbar, there is an IDE-option to turn in off, uncheck it at Debugging->XAML Hot Reload-> Enable in-app toolbar.